# php pass unknown number of values to mysql prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've been googling for the past few hours for a solution but nothing that fits my need. These [insert array with keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056528/insert-php-array-into-mysql-table) works if the array has a key that matches the database columns, [insert array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478632/insert-data-into-mysql-using-php-array) this works if the columns matches the values (bind each column to a value) and others that are similar but can't find anything that works for my situation.

I've an array that's posted through a jquery multiple select option, it's then stored in a `$eng` and passed to a function.

Here's the result of a **var_dump $eng** (the array).

> { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "Games" [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056528/insert-php-array-into-mysql-table)=> string(5)
>   "Music" [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478632/insert-data-into-mysql-using-php-array)=> string(4) "Walk" } }

The array can have from 1 value to 5. All depending on what the user selects. I will like to insert the values in a database.

Here's my code so far, it works if the array count matches my table columns, otherwise I get an error `Insert value list does not match column list` I need any recommendation to be in a prepared statement for obvious reason, but I just can't figure it out.

```
public function addActivity($eng, $reqid)
   {

    $act = implode("','",array_values($eng[0]));    

    $query  = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO reqactivity VALUES ('NULL','$reqid','$act')");
            $query->execute();

            var_dump($eng);
   }
```

Here's the table structure

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reqactivity` (
>   `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `reqid` int(12) NOT NULL,
>   `act1` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
>   `act2` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
>   `act3` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
>   `act4` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
>   `act5` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

Comment: What's the structure of `reqactivity`?

Comment: you are selecting only the position 0 in the array. Did you try do it with a cycle like a `for`and use it to do the insert for each value in the array?

Comment: Would that be in the same row or different row foreach value in the array? I want to create just one row and the array goes into a different column on the row.

Comment: @keez How do you expect that to work? if there are ten values in the array and only 5 act columns, where do you plan to put the other 5 activities?

Comment: @Adelphia I was going to add more columns. I know the activity list will grow and as new activities are added new columns are created.  Are there any down side of storing all activities in one column, comma separated, knowing that it will grow?

Comment: @keez No, there aren't any downsides to doing it that way. And with a variable number of indexes that's really the only way you *can* do it.

Comment: But.. If you can make sure that the array always has the same number of indexes as there are columns, then that's ok too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrap that table.

If you have phpMyAdmin, open the table,  go to operations, then drop table. Now do this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reqactivity (
id int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
reqid int(12) NOT NULL,
activities varchar(250) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

Then use this to insert your activities. They will all be in one column separated by a comma. You can't just cram any old data into any old column and hope that there will be enough or not too many.

```
$query = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO reqactivity VALUES (NULL, :rid, :act)");
$query->execute(array(":rid"=>$reqid, ":act"=>$act));
```

Can't leave execute empty. See PDO on the manual.

### Alternative approach

If you want to make this work without changing your table you need to somehow make sure that that array always has exactly 5 values. no more, no less. If you can do that then change your query the way @aland put it in his answer.

Comment: Don't quote "NULL" unless you mean to actually insert the word "NULL".

Comment: I am getting the same error with this. SQLSTATE[21S01]:`Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: @keez Without the structure of your table to look at I can't give you a query that will work. How many columns (fields) are in your table and what are they called?

Comment: I just included the table structure

Comment: I am trying this now. Just thinking if there are any downside to saving everything in one column knowing that activities could grow.

Comment: Why would there be downsides? just make sure that there are enough charachters alloted to that column. You actually might want to chage the `varchar(15)` part to `varchar(150)` or something.

Comment: Seems like a perfect case to make a new table `activities` and store each activity as a row in this table. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 2):

You should be using parameters (named is possible but I just use ?) for the prepare statement. I'll assume PDO - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

```
$values = array_merge(array('null', $reqid), $eng[0]);
$placers = array_fill(0, count($values), '?');
$query = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO reqactivity VALUES (".implode(',', $placers.")");
$query->execute($values);
```

Comment: ah, I'm too used to my library and forgot the native methods. Will edit

Comment: That's better syntax, but even still. He's talking about an unknown number of fields. You're basically just throwing data in cells without any regaurd to whet they are. His original statement implied 3 columns.

Comment: This is why I asked for the table structure of reqactivity - he mentioned that up to 10 values can be selected by the user so the table may have structure of (pk, fk, field1,field2,field3..field10). If the 10 fields have different names, then for sure named parameters (your answer) would be better

Comment: It looks like he just want a comma delimited list in one of the columns.

Comment: the array should be inserted into different columns on one row

Comment: I didn't use this but I up-voted it because I think it's a good solution if I can predict the number of values.